# Eigendecomposition makes me wonder in numpy

Tags: numpy, eigenvalue, eigenvector, matrix-decomposition

I test the theorem that A = Q * Lambda * Q_inverse where Q the Matrix with the Eigenvectors and Lambda the Diagonal matrix having the Eigenvalues in the Diagonal.

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as lg

Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors = lg.eigh(np.array([

    [1, 3],

    [2, 5]


]))

Lambda = np.diag(Eigenvalues)


Eigenvectors @ Lambda @ lg.inv(Eigenvectors)
```

Which returns :

```
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  5.]])
```

Shouldn't the returned Matrix be the same as the Original one that was decomposed?

Comment: shouldn't the last matrix be inversed not transposed according to theorem?

Comment: Yes you are right.  The transpose would be equal to the inverse when the matrix has orthogonal columns which is not the case always.  Thank you for reminding me that.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You are welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the function linalg.eigh which is for symmetric/Hermitian matricies, your matrix is not symmetric.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html

You need to use linalg.eig and you will get the correct result:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as lg

Eigenvalues, Eigenvectors = lg.eig(np.array([

[1, 3],

[2, 5]


]))

Lambda = np.diag(Eigenvalues)


Eigenvectors @ Lambda @ lg.inv(Eigenvectors)
```

returns

```
[[ 1.  3.]
 [ 2.  5.]]
```

As expected.