# How to compute variance decomposition proportions of correlation matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix-decomposition

I'm looking to identify collinear variables in my input matrix X. I'm able to get some metrics like VIF scores, condition number, condition indices, but unable to get variance decomposition proportions. Can someone please help me on how to compute variance decomposition proportions of correlation matrix in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigendecomposition makes me wonder in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487118/eigendecomposition-makes-me-wonder-in-numpy)

Comment: In combination with https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657433/correlation-matrix-in-python